# Color Asset not showing on iPad Device in Swift UI

Tags: ipad, swiftui

I am SwiftUI application , application deployment Info is iPhone only ,and defined color in Asset File as "Universal"
color is showing up fine when install on iPhone Device ,

but when installing on iPad Device color is not showing up.(but visible on Simulator)

color usage code:

```
 Text("privacy policy").foregroundColor(.appTheme)
                    .font(.system(size: 13).bold())
```

and our app is in review - but apple team is testing on iPad (which displays app in iPhone ratio) , but colors are not loading , and they can't see some buttons ,
so they have rejected the app.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there was the bug in Xcode , where it doesn't pick color assets from asset file , so had to create color extension file to pick color programmatically using RGB Color